# Internet Check in dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I have created a project in which it checks for continuous Internet Connection using Broadcast receiver.
Now if internet is available it shows nothing but as soon as i turn my internet connection off by scrolling from notification,it shows my alert box with error that no internet connection.but when i turn my internet turn on again from scrolling notifaction my alert box remains on Screen how to dismiss alert box.

I have tried to globally delcare my Alertd

//Code

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
            boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

            NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);



            if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){

               // alertDialog.dismiss(); not working showing Error
//Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            }
               else{
 alerDialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registration.this);
            alerDialogbuilder.setTitle("Internet / Wifi Connection Error ! ");
            alerDialogbuilder.setMessage("Turn on Wifi/Internet ");

            alerDialogbuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alerDialogbuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0);

                }
            });
            alerDialogbuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent iteer = new Intent(Registration.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(iteer);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_left, R.anim.slide_to_right);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            alertDialog = alerDialogbuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    };
```

//Calling on Resume

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
        this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
```

//inside on create

```
 this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this

initiate alert dialog in onCreate() like this , with your existing code you were creating new instances of alert dialog again and again and that is why dismiss() was not working

```
onCreate(){
 alerDialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registration.this);
            alerDialogbuilder.setTitle("Internet / Wifi Connection Error ! ");
            alerDialogbuilder.setMessage("Turn on Wifi/Internet ");

            alerDialogbuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alerDialogbuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0);

                }
            });
            alerDialogbuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent iteer = new Intent(Registration.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(iteer);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_left, R.anim.slide_to_right);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            alertDialog = alerDialogbuilder.create();

}
```

and your broadcast receiver looks like this

```
private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
            boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

            NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);



            if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){

              //dismiss dialog here
                alertDialog.dismiss();



            }
               else{
 //show dialog here
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    };
//unregister broadtcast here
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (this.mConnReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(this.mConnReceiver);
    }


}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTICE**:-

> unregister broadcast receiver in onStop() else there will be
>   exception and crash
>
> **DO NO REGISTER RECEIVER AGAIN IN ONRESUME()**

Comment: it worked for me but can uh help me out with how to stop broadcast receiver ?? and what if i am not using Broadcast reciever in android

Comment: Sure I will update code and if you throw exception and app might crash

Comment: You have to unregister broadcast receiver

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62135777/hide-button-if-not-data-in-recyclerview can uh help me out with this also

Comment: sir can uh please help me out with other problem ??
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62135777/hide-button-if-not-data-in-recyclerview